# VM Player 3D Drivers

Tags: 20.04, intel-graphics, 3d

I'm running ubuntu 20.04, with VMware Player 16.0.  When I try to create a VM with 3D graphics enabled, vmware complains that I do not have 3D drivers installed.

```
# glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 (CML GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Do I need to upgrade the video driver in order to enable 3D performance in the VM?  If so, should I use drivers from ppa oibaf, ppa graphics-drivers or something else?

-Robert

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the new VMware Player does not have access to the VM Tools downloads yet. I've been told it's coming soon, just need to be patient (only been a few days since the release). You can always go back to the previous v15.5 release for now, then upgrade when the new tools are available (btw, the old tools will work if you upgrade to v16 before the new tools arrive).

The (2) PPAs you mentioned won't help (both require real, not virtualized, GPUs).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I thought the problem was with my OS GPU drivers, but you're saying the issue is linked to the vm-tools.